# Complexity of Determining the Edges of Planar Convex Hulls

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

> **Question:**
>
> can the set of edges that resemble the convex hull ($CH$ for short) of $n$ points in the euclidean plane be determined in $O(n)$ time?

I know that the time complexity of determining the $CH$ of $n$ points is $O(n\log h)$ where $h$ is the number of points constituting to the $CH$ and is achieved by the [Kirkpatrick-Seidel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick%E2%80%93Seidel_algorithm), but that includes reporting the points of $CH$ in sorted order.

So, can the $\log h$ factor be saved if the <del>edges</del> vertices of the $CH$ can be reported in random order?

Edit:

incidently I realized that the set of edges apparently can't be reported in $O(h)$ when I turned on my computer and then saw the Aaron's comment about the pertinent related question.

The argument against the possibility of reporting the edges in $O(h)$ is simply that the *set of edges contains enough information to be able to also **sort** * them in $O(h)$ time via the following algorithm:

- assume that the $n$ vertices are stored in an array **V** and labeled with their index in that array
- determine the edges of the $CH$ in random order in $O(h)$ and store them in an array **H**
- label the edges in **H** with their index in that array
- create an **P** that contains pairs of indices of edges in **H** and initialize all entries with the pair (-1,-1)
- iterate over **H** and store the edge index in **P** in the positions of their adjacent vertices, overwriting one of the pair values that equal -1
- **P** now resembles a doubly linked list from which the sorted order of the edges of $CH$ *could* be reconstructed in $O(h)$ time

as the possibility of reporting the edges in sorted order in $O(n)$ time clearly contradicts the proven sharp lower bound for the complexity of sorting there is no advantage in reporting the *edges* of $CH$ in random (or rather: unspecified) order.

However with reporting the *vertices* of $CH$ in random order the situation is fundamentally different as there is no neighborhood relation that could be exploited to reconstruct the edges of $CH$ in $O(n)$ time

Comment: One can ask just for the bounding lines (rather than line segments) and the question is still interesting.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I like the question, but how would we find a bounding lines without knowing at the same time the two points from the set which are on that line? (Here I ignore the case that several boundary points are co-linear.) Granted, given the lines and the points of the boundary it does not seem easy to recover the edges. But could that happen without having that information and then forgetting it?

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz  I don't know the answer.  It's just that finding the lines seems to be the minimal requirement which has a chance of having the same complexity as finding the hull as an ordered list of vertices.  And I suspect it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been known for some time that the *unordered convex hull problem*—"just identifying the vertices on the planar convex hull, takes $\Omega(n \log n)$ time":

> Ramaswami, Suneeta. "Convex hulls: Complexity and applications (a survey)." Technical Reports (CIS) (1993): 264. [PDF download](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1272&context=cis_reports).
>
> Haverkort, Herman. "Finding the vertices of the convex hull, even unordered, takes $\Omega(n \log n)$ time--a proof by reduction from $\epsilon$-closeness." arXiv preprint [arXiv:1812.01332](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01332) (2018).

Comment: that is a really surprising result.

Answer (score 2):

I think not because it wouldn't be hard to go from the edges, given as pairs of points, to the ordered list of edges.

With complexity $n$ we can give each point an index in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ so that we can look up in one step the index from the point or the point from the index. Then given the unordered set of edges, supposing for now that each edge is reported in clockwise order, we can use $2n$ look ups to get an ordered list of edges. If the edges are reported as unordered pairs we can take an internal point (the average of some three points say) and use it to orient all the edges with complexity $O(n).$.

Here is a pertinent related question: 
Given numbers $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \cdots \lt x_n,$ but in a random order, we know that  $n \log n$ is the complexity to sort them. What is the complexity to return , in no special order, the set of $n-1$  ordered pairs $(x_i,x_{i+1})?$ The same indexing idea as above would seem to allow one to turn that into the sorted list in time $O(n)$ . The connection is that for the $n$ points $(x_i,x_i^2)$, finding the edges of the convex hull is the same as finding those ordered pairs.

**LATER** There seems a definitive answer. Here is a toy example to show what I was trying to say: Suppose that the input is $7$ points of which $4$ turn out to be on the boundary of the CH. The input might be a seven element array stored in memory addresses$100,200,\cdots 700.$ Each term is a three field record with $x$ coordinate, $y$ coordinate and third field (the only one that changes) initially NULL.

$\begin{array}{cccc}
100 & 7 & 1 & - \\
200 & 10 & 0 & - \\
300 & 0 & 0 & - \\
400 & 3 & 4 & - \\
500 & 0 & 10 & - \\
600 & 10 & 10 & - \\
700 & 5 & 6 & - \\
\end{array} $

Somehow we end up knowing the edges of the convex hull. I'm thinking that at this stage the array is

$\begin{array}{cccc}
100 & 7 & 1 & - \\
200 & 10 & 0 & 600 \\
300 & 0 & 0 & 200 \\
400 & 3 & 4 & - \\
500 & 0 & 10 & 300 \\
600 & 10 & 10 & 500 \\
700 & 5 & 6 & - \\
\end{array} $

I agree that we might then do one sequential pass through the array and return

- $(10,0),(10,10)$
- $(0,0),(10,0)$
- $(0,10),(0,0)$
- $(10,10),(0,10)$

I also agree that given just that list of edges, sorting would be as hard as sorting is. But that is because we threw away information.

With that data structure there is no issue of finding the address from the coordinates. We know the coordinates *because* we have the appropriate memory address (i.e. the index.)  So we can as easily (or more easily) visit the memory locations in order $100 \rightarrow 200 \rightarrow 600 \rightarrow 500 \rightarrow 200$ then STOP and return the ordered list of edges.

Comment: I had the same idea but I can't make it work.  If you have a set of $n$ arbitrary numbers, it is easy enough to assign each one an index from $\lbrace 1,\ldots,n\rbrace$, and to later retrieve the number with a given index.  But how do you retrieve the index for a given number?  The standard approaches either use a data structure with logarithmic cost per query (a balanced tree, or sorting), or have constant time only on average (a hash table).

Comment: @BrendanMcKay  if you have $n$ arbitrary numbers, store them in an array (that gives the index) Then the “edges” we somehow find can be represented in a second array of length $n$ which started empty and now has $j$ in position $i$ if value[i],value[j] is an edge. We are moving pointers rather than rearranging the array.

Comment: Aaron, in order to construct the second array you need to locate entries in the first array on the basis of the value they contain. Specifically, given an edge $x,y$, you need to find the positions of $x$ and $y$ in the first array in order to know which value to store in the second array.

Comment: I guess it depends on the details of the data structure. If the coordinates of the given points are (the first two fields of) records stored in a fixed array then an edge from from $x$ to $y$ is perhaps not indicated by putting the coordinates of $y$ into the third and fourth fields of the record for $x.$ instead a third field, initially blank, is set to $j$, the index of $y$. Then in one pass one can list the edges in no special order by: If record $i$ has third field no longer blank but now $j$ then list the coordinates at of record $i$ then those of record $j.$

Comment: After that, examine record $i+1$ to see if it has third field blank or not. Instead, one could, after dealing with record $i$, immediately consider record $j$ and in this manner present the edges in order.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I still don't get it.  You have a set $\lbrace x_i,y_i\rbrace$ of edges.  Now you want (I think) to make an array of records where the record with index $i$ has $x_i$ and also the index of $y_i$ (i.e. the value $j$ such that $y_i=x_j$).   But, given $y_i$, how do you find its index without some sort of search?  You can't locate an array element by its content in $O(1)$ time.

Comment: I might be thinking of it wrong. I added to the answer.

Comment: You glossed over the difficult part.  The input is a set of edges in no particular order, and your task is to put them into the order they appear on the convex hull.  In your second picture of the array, you assume the answer just appeared somehow (I agree it is easy from that point). For example, starting with the first picture, if the next input is "(10,0)-(10,10) is an edge", how you find the place 200 in the array corresponding to (10,0), and how do you find the value 600 to put in the third field there? (continued)

Comment: (continuing)  Of course it is easy if the inputs have the form "200-600 is an edge", but that assumes the list of edges has already been processed to consolidate the two places where each vertex is mentioned (which is the core of the problem).

Comment: The question  was "Can the set of edges that resemble the CH of $n$ points in the euclidean plane be determined in $O(n)$ time?" so given the vertices is it easier to find the edge list in no special order compared to in sorted order? My comment was that in going from vertices to edges you would have information making it as easy to report them in order. Now the question seems to be just finding the boundary points

Comment: I assumed the task you aimed to solve is that given in the first sentence of your answer.  That made sense, because if it can be solved in time $o(n\log n)$ (small "o"), it would establish a negative answer to the OP's question. If you had something else in mind, that's something else.